# Python Script break Linux while changing directories

Tags: python, linux, directory

This is the persmissions of the folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x 6 SuchithSridhar SuchithSridhar 4096 Mar 20 03:50 SDE-Journal
```

Then I run my program that works perfectly fine on my windows machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SuchithSridhar/Python-Code/SDE-Journal/main.py", line 1304, in <module>
  File "/home/SuchithSridhar/Python-Code/SDE-Journal/main.py", line 1264, in intro
  File "/home/SuchithSridhar/Python-Code/SDE-Journal/main.py", line 129, in preset_window
  File "/home/SuchithSridhar/Python-Code/SDE-Journal/main.py", line 142, in __enter__
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/SuchithSridhar'

On line 142: os.chdir(self.folder)
```

self.folder is just a folder that exists in the cwd

and once this program ends then I cant do anything from my linux terminal anymore...

```
bash: cd: Python-Code: Permission denied
```

this is if i had my terminal open, if i close and open the terminal

```
bash: /home/SuchithSridhar/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

why is this happening and how to change dirs without breaking my computer?

Comment: without seeing a [mcve] we can't help

Comment: This doesn't tackle the problem itself, but why do you need to use `os.chdir(self.folder)`? If you want to open a file from your code you can provide the path in the call to `open`.

Comment: I can't produce a minimal reproducible code, this is because each time this issue happens I have to run chmod on things and restart my computer. From what I deduce its the chdir function which i causing this problem... I can provide a github link : https://github.com/SuchithSridhar/Journal-Application

Comment: I have extensively relied on chdir in this program, I would have to refactor everything to not use it anymore.